# Extra lottery numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A lottery in Norway is done by marking $7$ out of $34$ empty fields. The first prize is won by matching all $7$ fields. It is also possible to mark $8$, $9$, $10$, $11$ or $12$ fields instead of the usual $7$. But if you do, you have to pay $8$, $36$, $120$, $330$ or $792$ times as much as if you would mark $7$ fields, respectively. Where do these numbers come from?

In addition to the seven winning numbers, they also draw $3$ extra numbers. In order to win second prize, you need $6$ winning numbers plus one extra number.

Comment: Yes, seven matching fields is first prize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you mark $8$ fields, you are $8$ times more likely to get first prize, since there are $\binom{8}{7}=8$ possible combinations of your chosen numbers that could make you win. Likewise, if you mark $9$ fields, you are $\binom{9}{7}=36$ times more likely to win. In general, the probability of winning first prize when choosing $n$ fields is $$\binom{n}{7}P,$$ where $P$ is the usual probability of winning. For $n=8,9,10,11,12$, this gives exactly the numbers you are asking about.

**Note:** $\binom{n}{k}$, read as "$n$ choose $k$", is the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from a set of $n$. To read more on that, and how to calculate it, you should read [this Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), or perhaps [this much less technical article](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html).